# How to keep count of elements in arraylist during for loop

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UseAllInArrasys
{

    class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            int num = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("=========Print numbers stored in ArrayList==========");

            ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();


            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter any number: ");
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("Invalid input");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("Enter any number: ");

                }
                numbers.Add(num);
            }

            foreach (var item in numbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }


        }

    }
}
```

I tried to get the below output
Say for example
When the code runs it execute and ask to
Console.Write("Enter any number: ");
If the user input blank or character then it jumps to
Console.Write("Invalid input");
Again it asks for
Console.Write("Enter any number: ");
As soon as user input is digits
code moves to next index in arraylist

But it should print the first digit entered after clearing the screen
same for second and so on

In the same code how can I control for loop, instead of i<= 5 how can I mention the arraylist count or size of likewise so that loop executes for that many times only.

I tried with
ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList(5);
for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.Count; i++) //Capacity

but it does not work

Comment: Please don't use `ArrayList`. Use an array, or a `List<>`.

Comment: OK! so mean to say what I want to achieve is not possible in arraylist ? please advise

Comment: You cant really use the list count as the loop counter if you are also adding numbers inside the loop. What is it you are actually trying to do? Examples can be useful.

Comment: Replace  your current for loop with a while loop (something like `while(numbers.Count < 5)` and the current while loop should be replaced with a simple if condition. YOu want to add to the numbers list or output an error message so its an if.

Comment: Read the official reference documentation for the ArrayList.Count property and what it signifies...

Comment: OK! I am trying to key in numbers using for loop in ArrayList, I want that for loop should execute till the count of arraylist i.e. ArrayayList numbers = new ArrayList(5), so I am using i<= numbers.Count

Comment: @MPC [just don't use ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74799718/659190), trust me, the .Net Framework improved greatly with version 2.0, back in 2002 (damn I'm old.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numbers.Capacity instead of Count, here's the modified code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            int num = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("=========Print numbers stored in ArrayList==========");

            ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList(5);


            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Capacity; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter any number: ");
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("Invalid input");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("Enter any number: ");

                }
                numbers.Add(num);
            }

            foreach (var item in numbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }


        }
```

And as per the additional question you can capture the userInput for for later use by changing the for loop like this:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Capacity; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter any number: ");
                string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                
                while (!int.TryParse(userInput, out num))
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("Invalid input: " + userInput);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("Enter any number: ");

                    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                numbers.Add(num);
            }
```

Comment: I have already tried and it goes into indefinite loop

Comment: I tested the above code and it works correctly

Comment: The other important change is in the for loop, should be < numbers.Capacity, not <=

Comment: Gr8 ! it worked

Comment: Can you help me with how to retain user input so that even after user input is invalid, but when user input is numeric than all past entered numbers should display so that he is aware as to what he has entered! Since I have kept clear() thats the reason screen gets cleared everytime for Invalid Input and so on

Comment: I've updated my initial answer above to include an example of keeping the user input

Comment: I tried and incorporated the same in my code but it goes in indefinite loop such that it keeps on asking Enter a number ---- Invalid Input and so on even if I do not input blank or character Pls advise! VS gives below error
Warning CS8600 Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

[Just don't use `ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0#remarks)

> **Important**
>
> We don't recommend that you use the `ArrayList` class for new
> development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0)
> class. The [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-7.0) class is designed to hold heterogeneous
> collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best
> performance. Instead, we recommend the following:
>
> - For a heterogeneous collection of objects, use the `List<Object>` (in
>   C#) or `List(Of Object)` (in Visual Basic) type.
> - For a homogeneous
>   collection of objects, use the [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) class. See [Performance Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0#performance-considerations)
>   in the [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) reference topic for a discussion of the
>   relative performance of these classes. See [Non-generic collections shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0006.md)
>   on GitHub for general information on the use of
>   generic instead of non-generic collection types.

Answer (score 0):

It'll loop through based on the array count.

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter any number: ");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Invalid input");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Enter any number: ");

            }
            numbers.Add(num);
             foreach (var item in numbers)
             {
               Console.WriteLine(item);
             }
        }
```

Comment: If you don't want to retain old value then clear the array after printing.

Comment: I want to retain old values while keying values but since I am validating that nothing except numeric is allowed and at that time I am displaying msg "Invalid Input" and then clearing the screen, I want that if user entered numeric then it should be displayed till the loop gets completed and at last it will print all the entered numbers

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps get the total count from the user and use it as the counter.

```
namespace UseAllInArrasys
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            var num = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("=========Print numbers stored in ArrayList==========");

            Console.Write("Enter how many numbers you want: ");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var totalCount);
            IList integerList = Enumerable.Range(0, totalCount).ToList();;
            var fixedSize = ArrayList.FixedSize(integerList);


            for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter any number: ");
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("Invalid input");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("Enter any number: ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"You entered {num}");
                numbers.Add(num);
            }

            foreach (var item in fixedSize)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: So this means that there is no way I can control the number of elements directly using ArrayList ? ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList(5);  ?

Comment: not sure, why you want to do it that way, but if you want then I have updated the answer with one way of doing so ! The list just internally grows, as soon as you add elements to it. So would be interesting to know a little background on why you want this way